# Laravel - find specific ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a page where users can post their statuses. Every status have something similar to like button. To do something with this button I need to find ID of the status where the button is clicked. I know how to find the first ID or the last ID or in between ID, but I'm struggling to find the specific ID where the button is clicked.

Can you point me in the right direction?

thank you

Comment: You need to use Javascript for this.

Comment: We're probaply going to need some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.target` refers to the element that triggered the event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function(event) {
        alert(event.target.id);
    });
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w3o20dtj/) is a simple example application.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ali. This is definitely the way to do it. If you would be so kind to help me how to pass this ID to controller? Once I have it in controller I know what to do but I'm not so good with javascript

Comment: Be kind enough to share your code please. I am no Gandalf.